# automatically refresh media wiki pages on update in Varnish

Tags: mediawiki, varnish, varnish-vcl

I've setup mediawiki behind Varnish. And I've figured out a way to get updates to the wiki to pass through to the web server. But of course any edits you make to the wiki site don't get updated unless you clear the varnish cache.

I tried putting this into the config in an attempt to get allow the site to be updated when you edit the wiki:

```
# Allows you to edit the wiki
 if (req.url ~ "&action=submit($|/)") {
    return (pass);
    ban(req.url);
}
```

How can I express this in the varnish VCL so that any time you edit the wiki, the varnish cache gets updated automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that in VCL, instead configure MediaWiki to purge updated pages:

```
$wgUseSquid = true;
$wgSquidServers = array('varnish IP 1', 'varnish IP 2', ...);
```

See [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSquidServers) for full docs.

Comment: Hi MaxSem,

I already have those options set:

$wgUseSquid = true;
$wgSquidServers = array( 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx.xx' );
$wgUsePrivateIPs = true;

Not sure why I have UserPrivateIPs set tho, or if it's needed. 

Any other ideas on why this is not working?

Comment: And I also have set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip; setup in vcl_recv on the varnish server.

Comment: So, do you see HTCP purge requests in tcpdump? Does your Varnish have varnishhtcpd running?

Comment: Not sure if i'm searching tcpdump right but this is what I tried with no results:

[root@varnish1:~] #tcpdump -nnvvS |grep HTCP
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes